# Spring Boot, Enable compression on multiple ports

Tags: spring-boot

In our spring boot application, we have a need for a secure and non-secure port. I have configured port 3000 to be secure via the application.properties file:

```
# Override default port setting
server.port=3000

# Enable SSL
server.ssl.key-store=classpath:keystore.p12
server.ssl.key-store-password=#####
server.ssl.keyStoreType=PKCS12
server.ssl.keyAlias=tomcat
```

And in some code to setup port 8080 as non-secure:

```
@Bean
public EmbeddedServletContainerFactory servletContainer() {
    TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory tomcat = new TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory();
    Connector connector = new Connector("org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol");
    connector.setScheme("http");
    connector.setPort(8080);
    tomcat.addAdditionalTomcatConnectors(connector);
    return tomcat;
}
```

Now, I want to enable compressed delivery, so in application.properties I added:

```
# Embedded Server Compression
server.compression.enabled=true
server.compression.mime-types=text/html,text/xml,text/plain,text/css,text/javascript,application/javascript,image/svg+xml,application/json
server.compression.min-response-size=2048
```

It would seem that this is a server-wide setting, but the 8080 port does not deliver compressed data while 3000 does just fine. If I understand correctly, the bean creating the 8080 connector is using the main server. I've tried several combinations of settings, such as enabling compression on the 8080 connector using old properties, to no avail. So I'm asking for a guru help to solve this.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You set compression at the protocol level, as shown below.

```
@Bean public EmbeddedServletContainerFactory servletContainer() {

    TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory tomcat = new TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory();

    Connector connector = new Connector("org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol");

    Http11NioProtocol protocol = (Http11NioProtocol) connector.getProtocolHandler();
    protocol.setCompressibleMimeType("text/html,text/xml,text/plain,text/css,text/javascript,application/javascript,image/svg+xml,application/json");
    protocol.setCompression("on");
    protocol.setCompressionMinSize(2048);

    connector.setScheme("http");
    connector.setPort(8080);
    connector.setSecure(false);

    tomcat.addAdditionalTomcatConnectors(connector);
    return tomcat;
}
```